# Is there any way to do remove without the query builder

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

is there any way to do remove without the query builder?

var query = Query.EQ("_id", id);
collection.Remove(query);

I updated my solution to 1.6 to use Linq query but I found I still need to use query builder to do the remove.
The documentation says that the support for query builder will be removed after 2.0.
Thanks!

Comment: For people arriving from google, please see cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/faYx-OXTtJE

Answer (score 0):

You could build it like this

```
var query = new QueryDocument("_id", id);
collection.Remove(query);
```

That said, you should be using Query.EQ. Only the DeprecatedQueryBuilder is going away.